# SVN-SSH Tunnel via 3rd machine?

Tags: macos, ssh, tunneling, ssh-tunnel, svn-ssh

I have a client that has SVN+SSH set up that I need to access.  Unfortunately I can't get my IP white-listed because I'm on Comcast and they have some security policy against that.  I do, however, have SSH access to another machine that I can SSH into that can also SSH into the SVN server (via a non-standard port)...  So the total loop needs to look like:

```
Local Computer (OSX)  --SSH-->  Server1  --SVN+SSH_4567-->  SVN Server
```

I know how to set up basic SSH tunnels, but I'm not sure how to set this up, or if it's even possible.  Help?  :)

Note that *ideally*, I can set this up somehow in `~/.ssh/config` and `~/.subversion/config` and not have to manually tunnel from A->B->C each time I want to make a commit/update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ssh -L 1234:svnserver:4567 server1
```

The tunneled connection will be

```
ssh -p 1234 localhost
```

To automate this somewhat you can add the tunnel connection to `~/.subversion/config`:

```
[tunnels]
tssh = ssh -p 1234
```

and then use `svn+tssh://localhost/path/to/repo` but I don't know of a way to automate creating the tunnel.

Answer (score 1):

Open SSH session to `Server1` and setup tunneling in that session:

```
ssh server1 -L 9000:127.0.0.1:svnserver:22
```

PS. You might want to check the ssh `man` page for syntax. I don't remember the correct flags to open a tunnel.

And then locally, you connect to the server using `svn+ssh://localhost:9000`

Comment: how does that get me to the SVN server?

Comment: er, sorry I forgot to type the `svnserver` part. Answer edited accordingly.

Comment: `ssh Server1 -L 1234:127.0.0.1:SVNServer:4567` gives _"Bad local forwarding specification"_  (4567 is the SVNServer's SSH port)